# TopAppBar with Tabs renders Tabs with incorrect color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to build component for displaying TopAppBar and Tabs in Jetpack Compose.

Here is the effect I want to achieve:
[image]

I made wrapper for Tabs:

```kotlin
data class TabElement<T : Enum<T>>(
  val id: T,
  @StringRes val label: Int
)

@Composable
fun <T : Enum<T>> Tabs(
  value: T,
  tabs: List<TabElement<T>>,
  onChange: (T) -> Unit
) {
  TabRow(
    modifier = Modifier
      .height(54.dp)
      .zIndex(2f),
    selectedTabIndex = value.ordinal
  ) {
    for (tab in tabs) {
      Tab(
        selected = value == tab.id,
        text = {
          Text(
            text = stringResource(id = tab.label).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT),
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
          )
        },
        onClick = {
          onChange(tab.id)
        },
      )
    }
  }
}
```

And then I used it with default TopAppBar:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun <T : Enum<T>> InternalTopBarWithTabs(
  title: String,
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit = {},
  tabs: List<TabElement<T>>,
  currentTab: T,
  onTabChange: (T) -> Unit
) {
  Column {
    TopAppBar(title = { Text(title) }, modifier = modifier, actions = actions)
    Tabs(value = currentTab, tabs = tabs, onChange = onTabChange)
  }
}
```

View structure is built correctly, however tabs color is incorrect (I double checked that and TopAppBar color is exactly my primary color set in MaterialTheme, so thge problem is with Tabs). It looks like this:
[image]
[image]

I think the problem is somehow related to contentColor property of Tabs, because I can achieve desired colors with `contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary`, but with this solution also content of tabs (single tab) is colored with primary color.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Remove the `.height(54.dp)` modifier in the `TabRow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `.height(54.dp)` modifier in the `TabRow` and apply it to the `Tab`

```
TabRow( modifier = Modifier
    //.height(54.dp)
    .zIndex(2f),
    selectedTabIndex = state) {
    titles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
        Tab(
            modifier = Modifier.height(54.dp),
            /* ...*/
        )
)
```

With the `.height(54.dp)` modifier in the `TabRow`:

[image]

Without:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for super fast answer. This solution works perfect in light mode (I still don't know why, is it some internal behaviour of Compose?). However, in dark mode the color is still not the same as TopAppBar.

Comment: @MaksymilianTomczyk In the dark mode is applied the Elevation Overlays to the `TopBar` (it is a `Surface`). Currently you can't apply an elevation to the `TabRow` but you can use something like `CompositionLocalProvider(LocalElevationOverlay provides  null) {
        TopAppBar(title = { Text("title") },)
    }`

Comment: It works but it applies elevation 0 to both elements (bar and tabs). Is there any option to apply some elevation to those elements using `LocalElevationOverlay`? I tried to apply `AppBarDefaults.TopAppBarElevation` but I cannot find any way to do it.

Comment: Finally I found a way to make it work with using two surfaces:
```Surface(elevation = 4.dp) {
    Column {
      TopAppBar(title = { Text(title) }, modifier = modifier, actions = actions, elevation = 0.dp)
      Surface(elevation = 0.dp) {
        Tabs(value = currentTab, tabs = tabs, onChange = onTabChange)
      }
    }
  }
```